# How do I know which cookie(s) are must to make a correct HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest

I am working on a download manager and trying to get cookie required contents using `HttpWebRequest`. I want to integrate my application to Chrome and so I can get the necessary cookie headers and values from the browser.

But first I need to know if cookie is required to get a content to download and which cookies are they. I can't find any helpful resource about this topic.

> This is what I imagine:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (WebRequest.Create(url)) as HttpWebRequest;
//At first, get if cookies are necessary?
//If it is, get the required cookie headers 
//Then add the cookies to the request
CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();
Cookie c1 = new Cookie("header1", "value1");
Cookie c2 = new Cookie("header2", "value2");
CookieCollection ccollection = new CookieCollection();
ccollection.Add(c1);
ccollection.Add(c2);
cc.Add(uri, ccollection);
req.CookieContainer = cc;
//Get response and other stuff......
```

How can I do these steps?

Comment: Look at this extension to Chrome: http://www.editthiscookie.com/. You can use it to see which the cookies are used by web request/response.

Comment: Thanks but I want to do it in c# code, i only need the required cookie header

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cookies required to get content from a server are specified by that server in the HTTP response's "Set-Cookie" header. The generic scenario is:

1. Client makes an HTTP request to the server (this could be a login page, or a download page)
2. Server responds with HTTP response that contains "Set-Cookie" header(s)
3. Client remembers all those cookies
4. Client uses the cookies stored in step 3 for all subsequent requests to the same server

Now, considering your scenario of integrating into Chrome, I imagine that the initial requests (steps 1 to 3) will not be done by your application, but by the Chrome itself. The cookies will be stored in the Chrome's cookie store. So what your application will need to do is to get from Chrome all cookies for the domain where you want to download from, and include those cookies in your request (step 4).

See [chrome.cookies](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies) document on how to use Chrome API to interact with its cookie store, and [Set-Cookie docs from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) for the in-depth description of how cookies are specified in the HTTP response.

Answer (score 2):

Try to capture the cookies from first request (a login page may be) and add all those in next request (download request). Something like below.

```
public void MakeRequest()
    {
        var container = new CookieContainer();

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/loginpage");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        request.CookieContainer = container;

        HttpWebResponse response = null;

        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        //once you read response u need to add all cookie sent in header to the 'container' so that it can be forwarded on second response
        foreach (Cookie cookie in response.Cookies)
        {
            container.Add(cookie);
        }

        HttpWebRequest downRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/downloadpage");
        downRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        downRequest.Proxy = null;

        //As you have added the cookies, this must response fine now
        downRequest.CookieContainer = container;
        response = (HttpWebResponse)downRequest.GetResponse();
        var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on actual download you want to perform and requirements of the server. Most servers will allow download regardless of cookies.
However, you can always send cookies just in case. What cookies you need? Here are some rules how browsers do it:
Cookie have Domain and Path attributes. Domain applies to subdomains.
So, if request is made for http://foo.bar.com/some/path following cookies will be sent:
-Those with domain com, bar.com and foo.bar.com without path
-Same as previous but having paths like /some or some/path etc.

It will not send cookies from other domains nor from domains listed above but with path not contained in path of request.

So, you would have to search for cookies in same way depending on URL of file you should download.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should integrate cookie because web sites requiring to identify user set data into cookie

without that token you can't perform the download

Cookie to be used are site dependent, you can't guess if the web site needs them or not, which are needed or not

If you are using .Net 4.5+, consider using "WebRequest.CreateHttp" static method
https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ff382788(v=vs.110).aspx

Keep track of the CookieContainer, it will eventually be populated with new cookie from response (Set-Cookie header in response)

note : cookie are linked to a domain (ie stackoverflow.com)
I suggest you install a cookie extension to your Chrome browser to play with

Comment: Does the response cookie container tell us which cookies are required? Also I have EditThisCookie extension for Chrome but there are types of login, security, onlyHttp cookies and there are more than one cookie that belongs to each of them. I can't understand which is the login cookie.

Comment: You can't figure out which cookies are required, even in the response. Cookies are site dependent, also can depend on the technology the web site is using (asp net, php...), the web developer could also use a cookie with a custom name. You have to deal with all cookies from the site's domain

Answer (score 1):

I would have added a comment instead, but don't have enough rep. You seem to be on the right track. Mateusz Radny's suggestion to use EditThisCookie will allow you to explore cookies you have in your browser, but for any particular web server you don't usually* need to decide which cookie is which (so you really don't need to care which is the login cookie).

The protocol for cookies is that the browser should send back the cookies that the web server initially sent to the browser for that particular website. Might help to read a bit more about cookies: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie (probably jump to *Implementation*, and then read up a bit in *Privacy and third-party cookies* because you really don't want to sharing cookies from one website with other websites).

So assuming you want to emulate what the browser would send, make sure your download manager also sends the same set of cookies that Chrome received from that particular website and it should work. Also avoid caching the cookies in your code, since your browser will update the cookies (e.g. delete expired cookies) and so you should always get them from the browser each time you need it.

*Note: Sometimes a cookie is marked for certain types of connections only or for use with a particular domain/sub-domain or Uri path. If set, then you should limit when you send those back based on if it matches the connection you're trying to make. Please research this separately (latest RFC specs: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265).

PS: The web server may send back new or updated cookies as part of the download request you made via your download manager. If you really want to be perfect, these should be copied from your download manager back to Chrome's cookie set (though I'm not familiar with the Chrome API so not sure how  hard that would be).